# How do I make so my spinner target links to a website?

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink, spinner

Hey, I'm really new with android development just started a few hours ago. I need to make a application for a school project and it needs to be done soon.

So far have I made a spinner with some alternatives to choose from. But here is my problem.
How do I make so when I click on one of the targets listed in my spinner so it links to a webpage.

I don't know how to use "AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener." or if it is necessary here or not.

I would be very thankful for some advices. thanks a head

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the onItemSelectedListener to your spinner:

EDIT:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);   
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);   
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
          int arg2, long arg3) {
      startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
             Uri.parse("http://yoururl.com")));
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

});
```

This will open the browser with your url.

Comment: Do I paste this in i src or in res- Layout/values? 
And where do I write in the ID of the spinner lists target? 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: You need to put this inside the Activity you have created in your src folder. Could you paste some of your code so I can more easily help you?

Comment: This is what I got under public void:

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: I get syntax error saying: "Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Syntax error on token "setOnItemSelectedListener", = expected after this token" at spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

Comment: I've edited my answer, look at the code block. Be sure to create the Spinner-object from your layout before you set the listener.

Comment: Sorry for all the noobish questions but what would i write in the .xml file to create a spinner-object. I mean i already have a spinner with lots of objects on already but the "OnItemSelectedListener" still doesnt work im affraid :(

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html